# What is this knob on a Martin-Baker Mk.4 ejection seat?

Tags: ejection-seat

I'm trying to find out what manual controls are on the Martin-Baker Mk.4 ejection seat and there's a black and yellow spherical knob by the pilot's right knee that has escaped my researches.  I know it isn't the inertia reel control or the manual override handle and the PEC is usually a green box off to the side.

Any ideas?

[image: MB Mk.4]

[image: MB Mk.4 detail]

[Pictures courtesy of Carlos Menendez San Juan](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Martin-Baker_Type_4P_Ejection_Seat_(3874323480).jpg)

Comment: Can you label the ones you do know? I would have said the one you're asking about is the manual override.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  None of the items I mentioned are visible in that photo.  The 'manual override handle' I was refering to is to separate the pilot from the seat without firing the ejection system (https://ejectionsite.com/emb2gen.htm) .  I looked at the document that Party_Ark linked to, and it's called the 'manual separation handle' there.

Comment: It is clearly a manual gearstick to control a manual transmission; also indicates this is a left-hand-drive aircraft.   (humour)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is the **Emergency Oxygen Manual Operating Handle**

[image]

> The emergency oxygen system has a gaseous oxygen storage bottle fitted
> to the back of the ejections seat which feeds its supply through an
> emergency oxygen demand regulator to the rear of the seat portion of
> the PEC [Personal Equipment Connector] and thence into the oxygen mask tube. Emergency oxygen is
> selected manually by pulling the **emergency oxygen knob**, or
> automatically on ejection as the seat rides up the rails. When the
> pilot separates from the seat after ejection, the separation of the
> man and seat portions of the PEC breaks the emergency oxygen supply
> and allows air to be breathed at ambient pressure.

source - [English Electric Lightning F Mk 36 & T Mk 5 Flight Manual](https://www.docdroid.com/NTaau7o/english-electric-lightning-f-mk-36-t-mk-5-flight-manual-pdf#page=115)

Comment: Excellent answer!  That document is perfect!